# Combine looping array PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

I have two arrays that are the results of two different database queries. I want to merge those two arrays fin the way I explain in the example below

This is the code that executes the first query:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT kec,pilihan,COUNT(pilihan) as total FROM votes GROUP BY pilihan");
$someArray = [];
foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
    array_push($someArray, [
        'data'     => $row['pilihan'],
        'total'    => $row['total'],
        'location' => $row['kec'],
        ]);
    }
```

This is the resulting array:

```
[
  {
    "data": "1",
    "total": "2",
    "location": "3524230"
  },
  {
    "data": "2",
    "total": "3",
    "location": "3524230"
  },
  {
    "data": "3",
    "total": "1",
    "location": "3524230"
  }
]
```

This is the code that executes the second query:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM owl_dptmaster GROUP BY kecamatan");
$someArray = [];
foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
    array_push($someArray, [
        'location' => $row['kecamatan']
    ]);
}
```

And the second array looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "location": "3524230"
  },
  {
    "location": "3524240"
  },
  {
    "location": "3524250"
  },
  {
    "location": "3524260"
  }
]
```

I want to merge those two arrays so that the result would be this array:

```
[
  {
    "location": "3524230",
    "data1": "2",
    "data2": "3",
    "data3": "1"
  },
  {
    "location": "3524240",
    "data1": null,
    "data2": null,
    "data3": null
  },
  {
    "location": "3524250",
    "data1": null,
    "data2": null,
    "data3": null
  },
  {
    "location": "3524260",
    "data1": null,
    "data2": null,
    "data3": null
  }
]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `I already tried with many methods but still fail` Can you show us your attempts? Without sharing your efforts with us, we may duplicate your work instead of providing a working solution. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of combining arrays, you could do the summarizing in sql with sub queries. Assuming you're using mysql.

```
$query = $this->db->query(
 "select owl.kecamatan,
  (select count(pilihan) from votes where kec = owl.kecamatan and pilihan = 1) data1,
  (select count(pilihan) from votes where kec = owl.kecamatan and pilihan = 2) data2,
  (select count(pilihan) from votes where kec = owl.kecamatan and pilihan = 3) data3,
 from owl_dptmaster owl
 order by owl.kecamatan"
 );
```

You could do this query and then build an array of  `"data" . $pilihan => $totalPilihan` which you push into the `$someArray` when the `$location` changes.

```
$query = $this->db->query(
"select owl.kecamatan as location, v.pilihan
from owl_dptmaster owl
left join votes v
on owl.kecamatan = v.kec"
order by 1, 2);
```

You have a results set with all the locations and votes.

```
 // Made of query results...
 $query = [

 [ "location" => "3524230", "pilihan" => "1" ],
 [ "location" => "3524230", "pilihan" => "1" ],
 [ "location" => "3524230", "pilihan" => "2" ],
 [ "location" => "3524230", "pilihan" => "3" ],
 [ "location" => "3524230", "pilihan" => "3" ],
 [ "location" => "3524230", "pilihan" => "3" ],
 [ "location" => "3524230", "pilihan" => "4" ],
 [ "location" => "3524230", "pilihan" => "4" ],
 [ "location" => "3524230", "pilihan" => "5" ],
 [ "location" => "3524240", "pilihan" => null ],
 [ "location" => "3524250", "pilihan" => null ],
 [ "location" => "3524260", "pilihan" => null ],
 [ "location" => "3524270", "pilihan" => "1" ],
 [ "location" => "3524270", "pilihan" => "1" ],
 [ "location" => "3524270", "pilihan" => "1" ],
 [ "location" => "3524270", "pilihan" => "20" ],
 [ "location" => "3524270", "pilihan" => "20" ],
 [ "location" => "3524270", "pilihan" => "30" ]

 ];
```

And here's a procedural routine to build `$someArray[]`.

```
 $someArray = [];
 $xRow = [];
 $oldPilihan = '';
 $total = 0;
 $oldLocation = '';

 foreach ($query as $row) {

 //echo $row['location'] . " - " . $row['pilihan'] . '<br>';

 $location = $row['location'];
 $pilihan = $row['pilihan'];

 if ($pilihan !== $oldPilihan) {

 if (! empty($oldPilihan) ) {
   $dataName = 'data' . $oldPilihan;
   $xRow[] = array($dataName => $total);
 }
   $total = 1;
   $oldPilihan = $pilihan;

 } else {

   $total++;
 }

 if ($location !== $oldLocation) {

   if (! empty($oldLocation)) {
     array_push($someArray, $xRow);
   }
   $xRow = [ 'location' => $location ];
   $oldLocation = $location;

   }

 }

 $dataName = 'data' . $oldPilihan;
 $xRow[] = array($dataName => $total);
 array_push($someArray, $xRow);

 var_dump($someArray);
```

Comment: How if pilihan is dynamicly?, because pilihan is active record

Comment: so pilihan is can be 1-20 or more, and data adjust pilihan number

Comment: How would your summary go? `"location": "3524230", "data1": "2", "data2": null, "data3": "1"` or `"location": "3524230", "data1": "2", "data3": "1", "data20": "6"`

Comment: I want to make `(select count(pilihan) from votes where kec = owl.kecamatan and pilihan = 1) data1` automatically without typing code manually

Comment: summary will be `"location": "3524230", "data1": "2", "data3": "1", "data20": "6"`

Comment: Edited answer with an incomplete answer. =[

Comment: Okay thank you @ourmandave , but this is not what I mean, this is correct code what I want

`$query = $this->db->query("select owl.kecamatan,
     (select count(pilihan) from votes where kec = owl.kecamatan and pilihan = '1') data1,
     (select count(pilihan) from votes where kec = owl.kecamatan and pilihan = '2') data2
     from owl_dptmaster owl group by owl.kecamatan");`

Comment: @ZMitnick Edited answer with working example. But my code is not the greatest. =\